# bind9 with mysql dlz start failed with Required token $zone$ not found

Tags: bind, dns-zone

bind 9.16.33 with mysql dlz start failed with `Required token $zone$ not found.`
detailed informations:

```
$ sudo named -d 0 -g
07-Dec-2022 14:54:31.043 starting BIND 9.16.33 (Extended Support Version) <id:35e9c6e>
07-Dec-2022 14:54:31.043 running on Linux x86_64 6.0.9-kagamine #2 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Sat Nov 26 18:02:37 HKT 2022
07-Dec-2022 14:54:31.043 built with '--build=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu' '--host=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu' '--mandir=/usr/share/man' '--infodir=/usr/share/info' '--datadir=/usr/share' '--sysconfdir=/etc' '--localstatedir=/var/lib' '--datarootdir=/usr/share' '--disable-static' '--docdir=/usr/share/doc/bind-9.16.33' '--htmldir=/usr/share/doc/bind-9.16.33/html' '--with-sysroot=/' '--libdir=/usr/lib64' 'AR=/usr/bin/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-ar' '--prefix=/usr' '--sysconfdir=/etc/bind' '--localstatedir=/var' '--with-libtool' '--enable-full-report' '--without-readline' '--with-openssl=/usr' '--without-cmocka' '--disable-backtrace' '--enable-linux-caps' '--disable-dnsrps' '--disable-dnstap' '--disable-fixed-rrset' '--without-dlz-bdb' '--with-dlopen' '--with-dlz-filesystem' '--with-dlz-stub' '--without-gssapi' '--without-json-c' '--without-dlz-ldap' '--with-dlz-mysql' '--without-dlz-odbc' '--without-dlz-postgres' '--without-lmdb' '--with-libxml2' '--with-zlib' '--without-python' '--without-maxminddb' '--disable-geoip' 'build_alias=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu' 'host_alias=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu' 'CFLAGS=-O3 -pipe -mavx2 -mfma -maes -Wno-unused-variable -finline-functions -fomit-frame-pointer' 'LDFLAGS=-O3 -pipe -mavx2 -mfma -maes -Wno-unused-variable -finline-functions -fomit-frame-pointer -Wl,-O3 -Wl,--as-needed -Wl,--hash-style=gnu -Wl,--sort-common -Wl,-x -Wl,-X'
07-Dec-2022 14:54:31.043 running as: named -d 0 -g
07-Dec-2022 14:54:31.043 compiled by GCC 11.3.0
07-Dec-2022 14:54:31.043 compiled with OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.1.1q  5 Jul 2022
07-Dec-2022 14:54:31.043 linked to OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.1.1q  5 Jul 2022
07-Dec-2022 14:54:31.043 compiled with libxml2 version: 2.10.3
07-Dec-2022 14:54:31.043 linked to libxml2 version: 21003
07-Dec-2022 14:54:31.043 compiled with zlib version: 1.2.12
07-Dec-2022 14:54:31.043 linked to zlib version: 1.2.13
07-Dec-2022 14:54:31.043 ----------------------------------------------------
07-Dec-2022 14:54:31.043 BIND 9 is maintained by Internet Systems Consortium,
07-Dec-2022 14:54:31.043 Inc. (ISC), a non-profit 501(c)(3) public-benefit
07-Dec-2022 14:54:31.043 corporation.  Support and training for BIND 9 are
07-Dec-2022 14:54:31.043 available at https://www.isc.org/support
07-Dec-2022 14:54:31.043 ----------------------------------------------------
07-Dec-2022 14:54:31.043 adjusted limit on open files from 4096 to 1048576
07-Dec-2022 14:54:31.043 found 28 CPUs, using 28 worker threads
07-Dec-2022 14:54:31.043 using 28 UDP listeners per interface
07-Dec-2022 14:54:31.075 using up to 21000 sockets
07-Dec-2022 14:54:31.078 loading configuration from '/etc/bind/named.conf'
07-Dec-2022 14:54:31.078 reading built-in trust anchors from file '/etc/bind/bind.keys'
07-Dec-2022 14:54:31.078 using default UDP/IPv4 port range: [32768, 60999]
07-Dec-2022 14:54:31.078 using default UDP/IPv6 port range: [32768, 60999]
07-Dec-2022 14:54:31.079 listening on IPv4 interface lo, 127.0.0.1#5353
07-Dec-2022 14:54:31.089 listening on IPv4 interface wg0, 10.123.112.20#5353
07-Dec-2022 14:54:31.092 listening on IPv6 interface lo, ::1#5353
07-Dec-2022 14:54:31.094 generating session key for dynamic DNS
07-Dec-2022 14:54:31.095 sizing zone task pool based on 1 zones
07-Dec-2022 14:54:31.095 Loading 'example_com_dlz' using driver mysql
07-Dec-2022 14:54:31.095 Required token $zone$ not found.
07-Dec-2022 14:54:31.095 Could not build find zone query list
07-Dec-2022 14:54:31.095 mysql driver could not create database instance object.
07-Dec-2022 14:54:31.095 SDLZ driver failed to load.
07-Dec-2022 14:54:31.095 DLZ driver failed to load.
07-Dec-2022 14:54:31.095 loading configuration: failure
07-Dec-2022 14:54:31.095 exiting (due to fatal error)
```

in named.conf :

```
zone "example.com" {
        type master;
        dlz example_com_dlz;
};

dlz "example_com_dlz" {
        database "mysql
                {socket=/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock user=root dbname=zonecc}
                {select id from example_com where zone = '%zone%' }
                {select ttl, record, case when type='TXT' then concat('\"', data, '\"') else data end from example_com where host = '%record%' and zone = '%zone%' }
                ";
};
```

in mariadb :

```
select * from example_com;
+-----+------------+--------+------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------+
| id  | host       | record | ttl  | data                                                                    | zone      |
+-----+------------+--------+------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------+
|   1 | @          | SOA    |  300 | ns0.example.com. dns.mail.example.com. 1670134076 7200 1800 604800 1800 | example.com |
|   2 | @          | NS     |  900 | ns0.example.com                                                         | example.com |
|   3 | @          | NS     | 1200 | ns1.example.com                                                         | example.com |
|  10 | ns0        | A      |  600 | xx.xx.xx.xx                                                             | example.com |
|  11 | ns0        | AAAA   |  600 | xxxx::xxxx                                                              | example.com |
|  12 | ns1        | AAAA   |  600 | xx.xx.xx.xx                                                             | example.com |
|  13 | ns1        | AAAA   |  600 | xxxx::xxxx                                                              | example.com |
|  28 | hydrogen   | A      |  600 | xx.xx.xx.xx                                                             | example.com |
|  29 | hydrogen   | AAAA   |  600 | xxxx:xxxx                                                               | example.com |
...
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems you need to use `$zone$` instead of `%zone%`. I also suspect that you need to replace delimiters for other variables like `%record%` too.